self hosted GitHub action runner not able to create .next
I am trying to deploy nextjs app with python backend and while building, not getting .next
In my local it's creating the .next folder but not able to do it runner. I have added github log, deploy.yml and Package.json for your reference.
Github Action log:
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4
   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types ...
   Collecting page data ...
   Generating static pages (0/6) ...
   Generating static pages (1/6) 
   Generating static pages (2/6) 
   Generating static pages (4/6) 
 ✓ Generating static pages (6/6) 
   Finalizing page optimization ...
   Collecting build traces ...
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    17 kB           107 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          869 B          82.7 kB
└ ○ /search                              2.02 kB          92 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            81.9 kB
  ├ chunks/938-973fd475f3395692.js       26.7 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-6532a1a12736ec51.js  53.3 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-9f89b1569ca96400.js  220 B
  └ chunks/webpack-073e1eb02d0477d3.js   1.68 kB
○  (Static)  prerendered as static content

Below is package.json which also installs requirements.txt for python backend.
Package.json:
{
  "name": "rag",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "fastapi-dev": "pip install -r requirements.txt && python -m uvicorn api.app:app --reload",
    "next-dev": "next dev",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run next-dev\" \"npm run fastapi-dev\"",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tabler/icons-react": "^2.47.0",
    "ai": "^2.2.31",
    "markdown-to-jsx": "^7.4.0",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

deploy.yml
name: Deploy to EC2

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main # Replace with your main branch name

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: '20.10.0'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: ls -l
    - name: Deploy to EC2
      env:
        PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        HOST_NAME: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST_NAME }}
        USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER_NAME }}

      run: |
        echo "Creating SSH directory..."
        mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
        echo "Adding private key..."
        echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        echo "Copying .next directory to EC2 instance..."
        scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r .next $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME:/home/$USER_NAME/chatbot-vector-search/
        echo "Running deployment script on EC2 instance..."
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME "/home/$USER_NAME/chatbot-vector-search/deployNextApp.sh"

